# Start activity on toolbar button click

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, toolbar

I have same toolbar in several activities in my App.
Toolbar contains button which should start new activity on click.

Of course I can add method to onClick in XML file which would open new activity, but the problem is that I would have to copy this function to all activities containig toolbar, what I want to avoid.

Can I just directly start new activity by onClick method? If no what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

OK here is some code I have a Button on my toolbar in an Activity and when I click it we go to a new Activity. Here is the XML code for the Button and the code that is in the Activity that send you on a trip

```
        <Button
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/color_White"
        android:background="@color/color_Transparent"/>
```

Code in the Activity

```
    /* this BUTTON is on the ToolBar click to ADD new record */
private void addListenerOnButtonAdd() {
// Navigate to DetailsActivity to ADD new DATA
    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( tb );

    tb.findViewById( R.id.btnAdd ).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentSP = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class );
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("FROM_LIST_ACTIVITY","true" );
            intentSP.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity( intentSP );
        }
    } );
}
```